# Is there a way to call a child's function from parent in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if it were possible to call a child's function inside the parent?

For example, can I use `useRef` to create a reference to the child and then call the function like that? Or is there another way?

```
// Parent
const init = () => {
const childRef = useRef();
childRef.current.child();
}

// Child
const init = () => {
function child() {

}
}
```

Comment: can you please add few more codes related to parent and child, and when you need to call the child function?

Comment: your idea is correct. using ref and useImperativeHandle hook you can achieve this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Comment: Check this out, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lzwpez

Comment: Can I pass down data like this to the child? -> `callChildFn(dataDown, wallArr, scene);`

Answer (score 6):

So you need to use  useImperativeHandle hook and wrap the child in forwardRef Hoc. useImperativeHandle gives access to functions which are written inside it to the parent component.

```
  const Child = forwardRef((props,ref)=>{
     useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        test: () => {
           //do something
        }
     }));
    });
```

in parent

```
const childRef= useRef();
<Child ref={childRef} />
```

Execute test function

```
childRef.current.test();
```

Answer (score 1):

By using ref you can point it out to a function too,

parent component,

```
export default function App() {
  const childFnRef = useRef(null);
  const callChildFn = () => {
    if (childFnRef?.current) {
      childFnRef.current("valueOne", "valueTwo", "valueThree");
    }
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Parent component</h1>
      <ChildComponent ref={childFnRef} />
      <button onClick={callChildFn}>call child fn</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

child component

```
//Ref forwarding is an opt-in feature that lets some components take a ref they receive,
//and pass it further down (in other words, “forward” it) to a child.
const ChildComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const childFn = (paramOne, paramTwo, paramThree) => {
    console.log("calling child fn... params are: ", paramOne, paramTwo, paramThree);
  };

  ref.current = childFn;

  return (
    <h2>child component</h2>
  );
})
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lzwpez)

Comment: Can I pass data down to the child too? I believe this works but for some reason `callChildFn(dataDown, wallArr, scene);` for example is not sending them down

Comment: @StasysMeclazcke updated, you have to pass the parameters from the parent as your comment, and the child function should accept the params, `const childFn = (paramOne, paramTwo, paramThree) => {....`

Comment: Can we have only an event handler bound to ref.current or multiple values can be added?

Comment: ` ref.current` should hold only one value, but you can be tricky to hold and object with functions

Answer (score 0):

When you use useRef you must have current after function. Like this

```
const childRef = useRef();
childRef.current.child();
```

An example in document: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

```
function TextInputWithFocusButton() {
  const inputEl = useRef(null);
  const onButtonClick = () => {
    // `current` points to the mounted text input element
    inputEl.current.focus();
  };
  return (
    <>
      <input ref={inputEl} type="text" />
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>Focus the input</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I am wondering if I can use a function from the child component. Not trying to return any html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, **but only if** the child component is class component.

Because functional component does not have an instance.

Let's say your child component is a class-based then you just need to have a createRef() inside parent and then pass that to the child.

Then, you can collect that instance from `.current` property of the ref and then trigger it.

Example,

Parent Component's constructor

```
this.childRef = React.createRef();
```

Parent Component's render

```
 render() {
return <ChildComponent ref={this.childRef} />
}
```

Child Component

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
    }

    doSomeThing = () => {}
```

And then at any event handler, you can execute child function as `this.childRef.current.doSomeThing();`

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs

Answer (score 0):

May be someone looking for functional component.
Here is heck without forwardRef and imperative Handler.

In Parent create child Ref like this,
const childRef = useRef()

In Child give ref passed from parent =>
ChildComponent ref={childRef} />

And finally in Parent use like this,
childRef.current.goToIndex({index:1)}